# Show that $\text{Ass}(M)\subset \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ and that the minimal elements of the two sets coincide (hence only depend on $M$).

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M\neq 0$ a finite $R$-module, and $0=M_0\subset M_1\subset \dots\subset M_n=M$ a chain of submodules with $M_i/M_{i-1}\cong R/p_i$, $p_i\in\text{Spec}(R)$.

1. Show that $\text{Ass}(M)\subset \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ and that the minimal elements of the two sets coincide (hence only depend on $M$).
2. Let $p$ be minimal in $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Show that in any chain as above, the multiplicity with which the factor $R/p$ appears is $\ell_{R_P}(M_P)$ (hence only depends on $M$).

In Dummit and Foote, there is a question in Section 15.5 number 26, which seems familiar.

> Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated module over the Noetherian ring $R$.
>
> 1. Prove that there are finitely many minimial primes $P_1,\dots,P_n$ containing $Ann(M)$
> 2. Prove that $\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$ is also the set of minimal primes in $Ass_R(M)$ and that $Supp(M)$ is the union of the Zariski closed sets $Z(P_1),\dots,Z(P_n)$ in Spec(R).

Are they the same?

Comment: May I ask what $\text{Ass}$ is?  Unfortunately, google search on $\text{Ass}$ is not helpful.  Adding the word "ring" into it makes things worse.  (I'm not trying to joke around, if that's what you think.)

Comment: @Batominovski A google search for "Noethrian ring Ass" led me to [associated prime ideals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime)

Comment: @KevinLong  Thank you very much.  I should have added that term in my search.  This is an unfortunate notation.